# Fixed position div displaying transparent on iOS6 Safari

Tags: css, position, positioning, fixed, css-position

I currently have a div that changes to fixed position at the bottom of the page when shown on a phone resolution and is supposed to display the author content. When clicking this div a menu slides up using jquery. At this time, the div displays transparent, but when clicking on the location the div should be, it slides the menu open just like it should.

I'm not sure what's going on, but all the debugging I have done has led to nothing. Has anyone else experienced this, or know how to resolve it?

Here's the HTML/CSS for that piece:

```
<div id="secondaryBox" class="span6 pull-right">
                    <div id="author" class="collapsed">
                        <?php if(!empty($user['avatarPath'])){?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $user['avatarPath'] ?>" class="avatar avatar-50 photo avatar-default" height="50" width="50" />
                        <?php }else{
                            echo get_avatar( $current_user, 50); 
                        } ?>
                        <h5><?php echo $user['displayName']; ?></h5>
                        <h6><span class="hidden-phone"><?php echo get_current_user_role($user['role']) ?>, </span><?php echo $user['schoolName']; ?></h6>
                        <div id="phoneCaret" class="circleCaret visible-phone"><b class="caret"></b></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ( current_user_can('read') ) { ?>
                    <div id="hiddenMenu">
                        <div class="addMenu hidden-phone collapsed">
                            <span>Additional Options </span>
                            <div class="circleCaret"><b class="caret"></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul id="slideOutMenu">
                            <?php if ( current_user_can('add_users') ) { ?>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=users"><i class="icon-th-list icon-white"></i> Manage Users</a></li>
                                <?php if(is_super_admin($current_user->ID)){?>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=import"><i class="icon-th-list icon-white"></i> Export Users</a></li>
                                <?php }?>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            <?php } 
                            if ( current_user_can('manage_categories') ) { ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php $networkURL ?>/wp-admin/network/sites.php"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Create School</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category"><i class="icon-tags icon-white"></i> Manage Categories</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=school_settings"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> School Settings</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            <?php }
                            if ( current_user_can('manage_network_options') ) { ?>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/network/sites.php"><i class="icon-globe icon-white"></i> Network Sites</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/options-general.php"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpengine-common"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i> WP Engine Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=limit-login-attempts"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i> Login Attempts</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=dashboard"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> My Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo network_site_url(); ?>"><i class="icon-globe icon-white"></i> Dewsly.com</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=profile"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> My Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://support.dewsly.com"><i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i> Support</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to logout?\')" href="<?php echo get_site_url(1); ?>/?my_error=logout"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#author{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#212121;
        height:70px;
        z-index: 1001;
        overflow:hidden;
        cursor:hand;
        padding:10px;
        border-top:1px solid #595555;
    }
#secondaryBox {
        height: 0px;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:70px;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto !important;
        left:0;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Comment: To add further clarification, id="author" is the one not displaying. I added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to id="slideOutMenu" and was able to see id="author" when scrolling it shows at the very end when the rubberband effect happens.

Comment: This is resolved. After quite a bit more reading the issue was having a fixed position div within a scrolling div. The information given in the comments of the post linked from here gave me the guidance. Although that is frustrating, at least I know how to resolve the issue now.

http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/

Comment: You should post your resolution as the answer and then accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately since I'm under 10 pts I have to wait 8 hrs before I can post the answer. I plan to do that tomorrow morning though. Thanks for reminding me though!

Comment: I gave you a little boost.

Comment: Much appreciated. I posted the answer and will accept it tomorrow when it allows me to. So many rules... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit more reading the issue was having a fixed position div within a scrolling div. The information given in the comments of the post linked from here gave me the guidance. Although that is frustrating, at least I know how to resolve the issue now.

http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

ugly but working solution for this;

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#fixedElement").css("right", "373px");
    }, 100);
```

I am not sure why, after you change/set position of element, it becomes visible again.